# Python HTTPS requests with proxy not working

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, proxy, vps

I developed a Python program that scraps webpage using `proxies`, all works fine and I decided to buy a vps to run it 24/7. I'm using a list of **working** proxies.
However, when running this script on my VPS server (`contabo`) I got this error:

`ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.xxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))`

When I remove `proxies=proxy` in my `requests.get()`, everything works.
I discovered that this issue happens with every `HTTPS` website.
I can request like `http://mon-ip.com` with no problem using my `proxies`.
I can also `curl -x proxy:host url`, and it seems working

I already whitelisted my vps ip for the proxies.

I really don't know where the problem could come from.